# How to disable users to go to folders in my directory via the url bar on my website? Is it safe for users to look into my directory like that?

Tags: .htaccess, file-permissions

Ive made a website, but anyone can get into the files in the directory of my website. For example if you type "www.mysite/css/stylesheet.css" you get to see all my css code. Now its not a problem that a user can see my css.

I was wondering if it is safe that users can see into my directory like that?

Comment: A css has to be accessed publicly else how you want to apply it to a public website?

Comment: Yeah I know, it was an example. I was more wondering if it is safe that users can see into my directory like that?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a login system because if so you can use the session to check if they are logged in. if not you can always just make a session using `Session_start();`
and then check if they `if(!$_SESSION['login_user']){
    header("location:../index.php");
          exit;}` for example. i suggest using a login system for it though this isn't really a css related question. more a php html question.

Comment: Thanks! No I dont have a login system, its more like a simple information/contact website.  I was more wondering if it is safe that users can see into my directory like that?

Comment: @Norris Ah well it is safe since they can't change anything about it. all they can see is what the style looks like though really they wouldn't understand much of it seeing as it's a coding language and users don't have too much knowledge of such things most of the time. so no worries